# Share specific files in folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, power-automate, onedrive-for-business

I have a folder of spreadsheets and I need to share specific spreadsheets with specific users and be able to replace the spreadsheets occasionally with files having the same name. I do not want the users to have access to the other files. Is there a way to keep the sharing function on when the files are replaced or would I need to reshare each one?

I also want to notify the users when their files are updated and  this process covers that by adding the naming Condition as outlined here: [Send email when file of a specific name is created or modified](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292744/send-email-when-file-of-a-specific-name-is-created-or-modified).

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting a file does not affect item permissions. Follow below steps:

1. Create SharePoint group (SPGroup) from 'People/Groups' under site settings. Make sure not to assign access level yet
2. Go to documents library and open item permissions of the documents that you want 'to restrict to' or 'provide access to' and break the inheritance
3. Grant access to the newly created SPGroup with required access level (preferably Read)
4. Open SPGroup and add the users who need to access the file
5. Repeat steps 2 to 3 to document items that you want to limit access to

When your new file comes in with same name, it will just overwrite the existing file with no impact to the permissions. Thus making it always available to users in SPGroups and other users on the site.

Comment: If each of the documents will be shared with a different user, why is it necessary to create the SPGroup? After breaking the inheritance, could I just create the documents library and set the permissions for each document in the folder?

Comment: Yes, you can break the permission on document (item) level. But, managing it will be difficult as you have to manage each item. To ease this, create a column (Users) in document library of type Person/Group and select 'Allow multiple'. Then create a workflow that will run on item creation/modification, that will (1) remove existing permissions (2) grant Full Control to 'Owners' SP group and give 'Read' access to everyone in Users column.